# Should we close question that keeps being bumped by Community?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, community-user

This question, [Compare two files and write it to "match" and "nomatch" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792432/compare-2-files-and-write-it-to-match-and-nomatch-files), has appeared this morning as modified by Community.

As I understand it, Community bumps old questions occasionally on some algorithm.

However, this particular question was also bumped a month ago. At the time I added a substantial answer, because the question has had so many views. OP no longer exists. The question is from 2009. It already had four answers.

The previous answers were not very good, but then the OP was not asked for clarification of what was required at the time.

The question has had a further 500 views in the last month.

This seems a waste (another question could have been bumped instead).

On the one hand, nearly 13,000 have viewed the question.

On the other, none of those near 13,000 have thought to upvote an answer, even those 500 from the last month.

A lot of people are looking at it, so that might argue against Close. But we can't demonstrate that anyone is getting anything from the answers.

Should it be closed? It is not a complete question that can be answered specifically for the specific OP (we don't each know which SORT product they are using), but it is a common general question - which also has many answers elsewhere easily found by searching the web.

Perhaps I should have tried to flag it for Close last month? Hindsight is so useful later on...

Comment: I have copied the text of my answer, so I have no problem with close/delete. It also clicked that an Upvote can get it off the Community Bump hitlist, so I've made my answer CW so it doesn't seem like begging for an Upvote.

Comment: And the famous Meta effect strikes again... congrats on your first upvote there!

Comment: :-) And some kind soul has edited. Now it has some tags which will present the niche to a wider audience, and rat them off (perhaps). I was going to comment that it was not possible to edit the question in any helpful way...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd more Meta-effect. The question got a new Upvote, and even a Favourite (sp?)!

Comment: You're on a roll! Favorite, based on the tooltip. American English. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No need to close or delete just because there are no upvotes.** The question appears totally on topic.

That said, the reason for the lack of upvotes is most likely because it's a "niche language", I never even heard of JCL until now. Probably there are only very few selected users having 15+ rep with enough knowledge on this language to be able to judge good or bad answer.

Those views you see can be from random visitors without any account, so while they see and read your answer they can't upvote or comment.

Bottom line, do your best to improve such questions if possible, post the best answer you can and let it be.

Comment: Another click moment. When I find some useful answer (outside my niche) I get a little reminder to upvote if helpful. I now realise I must have been automagically logged on, so I wasn't anonymous... and thought that the drive-bys got the same suggestion...

Comment: @Bill you mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oSUK0.png) by "reminder"?

Comment: No. Now that I look, it seems to be specific to AskUbuntu: `Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.` This is when landing from an internet search. Doesn't have anything similar from a couple of other SE sites.... When I `close` that, I'm logged on on AskUbuntu, so I don't know what someone who is not on AskUbuntu would see.

Comment: @Bill you can always use Incognito mode to appear to be total "stranger"... ;)