# Marking whether you answered a question or not

Tags: feature-request, answers

The Community bot will automatically bump old, unanswered questions to the main site. I often see a question I could answer, but when I go to write it, I sometimes notice that I already answered it. It's not a huge time waster, but in my opinion it could be solved.

It's not a big problem on bigger Stack Exchange sites, like on Stack Overflow, but even on ones with a moderate following and number of new questions everyday (like on GameDev) it's noticeable.

Can we get some sort of marking on the main site? Maybe make the answer div be in a different color, like when it's answered, but with blue for example.

And I know that you could just visit the question and find it out in less than a minute, but do you really have to go in a house, to find out whether it's burning or not?

Comment: Well I mean, you really ought to be taking a look at existing answers anyways, first, to make sure that any new answers you post are adding something new and useful, to review and vote on existing ones, etc.

Comment: @JasonC What?  The request is asking for a way of seeing that you've already answered a question from the question list, to avoid re-reading through a question you don't remember already answering.

Comment: Well [here's a user script that does it](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/HaveIAnswered.user.js). It won't work if your answer is not on the first page of a multipage post (have to fallback on API for that and I don't have time right now).

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm against this. If I write an answer somewhere, and that Q&A gets bumped, it encourages me to *review* that answer, to make sure that it **doesn't**:

- **Contain any misinformation I may have provided.** This is a rare chance, but if the question has been active, had the answer contained some false information, someone would've pointed me in the comments, but since the question has been getting low views, chances of errors are high.
- **Need any new information** or perhaps I might've learned something on the go which I might now want to add. We're learning *all* the time. We learn new things everyday, if I've learned something after the answer was posted, there's a high chance that the answer can be further improved.

As Shog9 has already touched upon this in his post: [How can we make the purpose of Community "bumping" more obvious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279203/359094) that Q&A all in all needs **feedback**. I feel that, *that* feedback must also come from *you*.

It also needs **attention**, less people visiting that post means that there's a high chance of a error creeping in as the post becomes more and more outdated:

- Do the links I've posted still work?
- Are there any recent changes in the documentation of a code that I had then posted needs to be mentioned now? , etc.

**Adding a warning that you'd answered this question discourages *all of this***. Still, open up the answers you've already posted – regardless of whether they're bumped by the community. Think for a while if you can make it better or see if there are any comments to your answer.

Sometimes, I don't reply to comments if I've more pressing things to attend to; and now if I'm coming back to my answer when I've more time to spare and there *are* unanswered comments, they can now be taken care of. This may seem trivial if the community is small, but in the long run, revisiting old answered questions is always a good thing. Don't worry about wasting a few seconds, you're making StackExchange better every time you fix a thing.

Comment: I mean, if you *want* to review your answer again to check these things you still can, even if you know that you answered it when you opened the question, and if you *don't* plan on reviewing your answer again when coming across it again then you're not suddenly going to do it just because you didn't realize that you had already answered it...It's not like it's suggesting hiding questions you've answered from the question list.

Comment: @Servy If you've forgotten that you've answered a question then you're never going to review it anyway. Let's face it, we write *so* many answers, the answers which we review are the ones which which face criticism, now given that you don't have views on that post, it would be a good idea to *self-criticize* the post. Also, having wasted a few minutes re-reading that question, you'll probably be more likely to review that answer of yours.

Comment: `If you've forgotten that you've answered a question then you're never going to review it anyway` That would be a point in *favor* of the proposal, not a point *against* it.  Again, I'm not saying that reviewing your answers is bad or that people shouldn't do it; I'm saying that adding this feature in no way inhibits people from reviewing their own answers, if they're the type of person that likes reviewing their own answers.

Comment: I'm not talking about bumps from edits, I'm talking about community bumps